# Sftp exception when trying to get file names with SharpSSH

Tags: sftp, directory-listing, sharpssh

I am using SharpSsh library to get file names from sftp server. Connection is OK but I get exception of type 'Tamir.SharpSsh.jsch.SftpException'  in this code:

```
_sftp.GetFileList("/outgoing")
```

When I was testing my code on my local sftp server on Windows the result was file names array. But in production we use sftp server on Linux and now I get this exception. Can anybody tell me how to specify path argument in GetFileList for sftp server on Linux.

Thanks!

Comment: Please share exception details with us.

Comment: There are no detailed information for this exception. Just this: Tamir.SharpSsh.jsch.SftpException: Exception of type 'Tamir.SharpSsh.jsch.SftpException' was thrown.
   at Tamir.SharpSsh.jsch.ChannelSftp.ls(String path)
   at Tamir.SharpSsh.Sftp.GetFileList(String path)

Comment: It has to have at least text message associated. Please inspect it again.

Comment: Are you sure the destination folder has enough permissions for the user to perform a folder list?. Remember the sftp server (ftp over ssh) use the same permissions that the user. Log with ssh console and perform a "ls" command being logged with that user to see if files get listed.

Comment: Carlos Landeras, I was successfully connected to sftp with this user with putty ssh client. I think this problem is because of the difference between folder full path in Linux and Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to make it work removing the initial slash:

_sftp.GetFileList("outgoing")